# How to configure custom logging in standalone JBoss

Tags: java, docker, wildfly, jboss7.x, log4j2

I'm trying to set a custom log configuration (in an external file) for an application that runs over JBoss EAP 7.2 in a Docker image but I haven't been capable of make it works.

I have an application that uses an external log4j2.xml file for the logging configuration. The path to this file is set in the property -Dlog4j.configurationFile.

The application runs in JBoss EAP 7.2, and when I run it in local (Windows) the logging configuration is properly defined, either running it in Eclipse (setting the property in the server --> launch configuration --> program arguments) or directly executing the standalone.bat (setting the property in the standalone.conf.bat file).

The problem comes when I try to execute the application in a Docker image (and I suppose that the same would happen in a Linux OS). I comment the logging extension and subsystem, and the application starts correctly, but with no logs.
I have tried exactly the same in WildFly, and it works without any problem, both in Windows and in a Docker image.

Considering the common points between JBoss and WildFly, I though in simplifying the standalone.conf from JBoss as much as possible and get it similar to WildFly.

I has commented this part of the original standalone.conf:

```
. $JBOSS_HOME/bin/launch/files.sh

JBOSS_MODULES_JAR=$(getfiles jboss-modules)
JBOSS_LOGMANAGER_JAR=$(getfiles org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager)
WILDFLY_COMMON_JAR=$(getfiles org/wildfly/common/main/wildfly-common)

# for newer WF, these modules have changed names. We try the old ones first
# then the new ones for compatability

JBOSS_JSON_JAR=$(getfiles org/wildfly/javax/json/main/javax.json-1)
if [ $? -ne "0" ]; then
    JBOSS_JSON_JAR=$(getfiles org/glassfish/javax/json/main/javax.json-1)
fi

if [ $? -ne "0" ]; then
    echo Unable to locate a javax.json JAR, aborting.
    exit 1
fi

JBOSS_JSON_API_JAR=$(getfiles org/wildfly/javax/json/main/javax.json-api)
if [ $? -ne "0" ]; then
    JBOSS_JSON_API_JAR=$(getfiles javax/json/api/main/javax.json-api)
fi

if [ $? -ne "0" ]; then
    echo Unable to locate a javax.json API JAR, aborting.
    exit 1
fi

AB_JOLOKIA_PORT=$((${AB_JOLOKIA_PORT:-8778} + ${PORT_OFFSET:-0}))
export AB_JOLOKIA_PORT

# add jolokia options
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} $(/opt/jolokia/jolokia-opts)"

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:${JBOSS_MODULES_JAR}:${JBOSS_LOGMANAGER_JAR}:${JBOSS_JSON_JAR}:${JBOSS_JSON_API_JAR}:${WILDFLY_COMMON_JAR} -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"

source /usr/local/dynamic-resources/dynamic_resources.sh
export GC_MAX_METASPACE_SIZE=${GC_MAX_METASPACE_SIZE:-256}
JAVA_OPTS="$(adjust_java_options ${JAVA_OPTS})"

# Make sure that we use /dev/urandom (CLOUD-422)
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"

# White list packages for use in ObjectMessages: CLOUD-703
if [ -n "$MQ_SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES" ]; then
  JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=${MQ_SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES}"
fi

# Append to JAVA_OPTS. Necessary to prevent some values being omitted if JAVA_OPTS is defined directly
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS_APPEND"
# add hawkular options
if [ -n "${AB_HAWKULAR_REST_URL:+x}" ]; then
  # we need to configure java logging for hawkular
  AB_HAWKULAR_AGENT_OPTS="$(source /opt/hawkular/hawkular-opts && get_hawkular_opts) -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
  JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} ${AB_HAWKULAR_AGENT_OPTS}"
fi

# add prometheus options
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} $(source ${JBOSS_CONTAINER_PROMETHEUS_MODULE}/prometheus-opts && get_prometheus_opts)"
```

But it fails:

```
Could not load Logmanager "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.jboss.modules.JDKSpecific.getSystemClass(JDKSpecific.java:180)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:395)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:195)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:181)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:523)
WARNING: Failed to load the specified log manager class org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logmanager/Level
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:340)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:320)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:593)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logmanager.Level
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.jboss.modules.JDKSpecific.getSystemClass(JDKSpecific.java:180)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:395)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        ... 5 more
```

It's true that in the original standalone.conf there were some references to a "LogManager",and if I restore them, the application starts again, but without the logs. So this makes me think that the trick is related with it.

I have tried other alternatives like setting the `<use-deployment-logging-config value =" true "/>` in standalone.xml and locating the log4j2.xml file into the application's WAR, and it works, but I need the file to be out the application.

I would appreciate any idea or suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `use-deployment-logging-config` to `false`? The default is `true` and it sounds like you might want it set to `false` if you want to use your own log4j2 configuration. You might also need to set the `add-logging-api-dependencies` to `false` as well.

Comment: I have tried it right now:
`<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:6.0">
 <add-logging-api-dependencies value="false"/>
 <use-deployment-logging-config value="false"/>
</subsystem>`
but no logs appear. I tried the specified at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-PerdeploymentLogging (with `true`), but in that case, it is necessary to include the log4j2.xml into the /WEB-INF/classes directory in the WAR

Comment: Yes you would likely have to include the log4j2.xml configuration file in the deployment.

Comment: The problem is that it's necessary that the file is external. If there would not be other option, we could think about it, but if it is working properly in JBoss in Windows, and in Wildfly in Windows and Unix, there should be another way for JBoss in Unix

Comment: I'm no Docker expert, but you'd need to do it the Docker way. It really should work the same in WildFly and EAP 7.2 for sure.